# Filter Get-Childitem to contents of CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, get-childitem, copy-item

I am trying to filter a `Get-Childitem` cmdlet with the contents of a CSV.

CSV Contents:

```
Files
------
B000000001
B000000002
```

Actual File Names:

```
B000000001.PT01.jpg
B000000002.PT03.jpg
```

This is what I have:

```
$ASINs = Import-Csv "C:\share_test.csv"
foreach($ASIN in $ASINs){
   echo $ASIN
   Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\test1" -Filter "*$ASIN*" | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\test2"
}
```

The alike items are not copying, but echoing the `Get-Childitem` cmdlet is also not picking up the files. Can anyone point out the error in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Probaly because you have to call the Filenames like this in the echo `$ASIN.Files` this should display the filesnames, and to use it in the Filter something like `"*$($ASIN.Files)*"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Import-CSV` the header of each column becomes the property name. So each row of your csv is an object with a Name property rather than an array of strings like you would get from `Get-Content`.

You can use the subexpression operator `$()` to interpolate `$ASIN.Files` inside your filter.

```
$ASINs = Import-Csv "C:\share_test.csv"
foreach ($ASIN in $ASINs) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\test1" -Filter "*$($ASIN.Files)*" | Copy-Item -Destination 
    "C:\test2"
}
```

Comment: Perfect! And thanks for including additional information. For anyone else looking for more info on this answer check out:
https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html

Comment: Upon further testing, the provided code is moving all files, not limiting the copy to items in the CSV. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Garrett I've tested this working for me. Are you sure that the header of your CSV matches and that there are no blank values in your csv?

Comment: Ben you are correct again! The header was changed, so using "*$($ASIN.Newheader)*" I am getting the desired results.Thanks so much.